# Find the area of the trig function

Tags: calculus, integration

I am brushing up on calculus II integration methods before taking differential equations. For some reason I am off by one number in my answer:

$$\int t\sin^2(t)\mathrm{d}t$$

using the identity $\sin^2(t)= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2t)$ and integration by parts we have:

$u = t, \mathrm{d}u = 1, \mathrm{d}v=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\cos(2t), v = \frac{1}{2}t-\frac{1}{4}\sin(2t)$

then:

$uv= \frac{1}{2}t\cdot t - \frac{1}{4}t\sin(2t)$

$\int v\mathrm{d}u = \frac{1}{4}t^2+\frac{1}{8}\cos(2t)$

putting them all together gives ans answer of:

$$\frac{1}{2}t^2-\frac{1}{4}t\sin(2t)-\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{8}\cos(2t)$$

However the back of the book says the answer is $$\frac{1}{4}t^2-\frac{1}{4}t\sin(2t)-\frac{1}{8}\cos(2t)$$

Why is my answer wrong?

Comment: Just combine terms containing $t^2$

Comment: Ummm... what is $\frac{1}{2} t^2 - \frac{1}{4} t^2$?

Comment: Both answers are surely identical!

Comment: Your answer is right. You only have to sum up the terms with $t^2$